# c# Giving focus back to parent form from other app

Tags: c#, process, focus, parent-child, setforegroundwindow

I'm trying to start and .exe from a child form of my main app, but the issue is that when I open the other .exe and it finish it's work (scan a finger print) and exit, my app gets minimized, so I try this:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd); 


    void method {
    ..........more code...........
     using (Process proc = new Process())
                    {
                        proc.StartInfo.FileName = "WindowsFormsApplication3.exe";
                        proc.Start();
                        SetForegroundWindow(proc.MainWindowHandle);
                    }
    ............code here..............
    }
```

but it doesnt work, my main app lost the focus, I find many solutions but any of them work for me, the other .exe is an app that I'm doing too.

Comment: How you start the .exe (finger print scanner)? Show me your code please, then I can help you...

Comment: the code of the finger print scanner?

Comment: That code you wrote to run .exe file...?

Comment: is the code showed above

Comment: I can't simulate this problem! in my system every thing is ok! The first app didn't minimized! and after closing 'WindowsFormsApplication3.exe' the focus returned to first app!... What should I do to see your problem?!

Comment: @user2461687 if you launch external program, when it exit your app auto get the focus (that is assume there is no third app get focus after your finger print lauch). If that is what you want, you don't need to have `SetForegroundWindow` function. If you want to lauch external app without loose current window focus, you must use other way.

Comment: OK! you want run an exe file without losing main app focus (during second app running)... yes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to active finger print window, your code is right! but add a waiting **before** SetForegroundWindow... like this:

```
while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle))
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    proc.Refresh();
}
```

and, If you want to active the caller form (main app) you don't need SetForegroundWindow! You can write:

```
while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(proc.MainWindowTitle))
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100);
    proc.Refresh();
}
// Then active caller form...
this.Activate();
```

Anyway, you need wait until finger-print window shown...

Comment: Thanks so much, the code was right I just implemented it in a bad way.

Comment: Could you help me in this problem? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35763868/c-sharp-flexcode-sdk-verification-not-working